# What's wrong with this JS code implemented in this context?

Tags: javascript, jquery, referer

http://jsfiddle.net/dS4r3/24/?q=hsbc

What this code does is it takes the referer of the page and if it contains one of the keywords that u see there it fills in with content that particular div (it also shows it)

As you can see it works fine when you click there and the div appears and its filled with that content containing the keyword "hsbc". In short, the function is being executed.

Now the problem is when i implemented the exact same code here, the function doesnt seem to execute: http://segurosendirecto.com.ar/cotizador-de-seguros-auto/?kw=hsbc

Things I've tried so far and didn't work :

- update jquery
- remove every other script just to make sure its not conflicting with this one.

Why is it not working on the second link?

Answer (score 1):

jsfiddle doesn't process referrer normally, so what you learn form jsfiddle in this case doesn't transfer to your website. Your website is processing referrer normally, and the referrer (`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9695194/whats-wrong-with-this-js-code-implemented-in-this-context`) simply doesn't contain the string `hsbc`.

What you need to do is create a new page (say, `new-page`) on your website that has a link to `cotizador-de-seguros-auto`, visit `new-page/?kw=hsbc` and click on the new link. Then your problem will vanish.

Comment: great, but what if u want to access directly, like pasting the url directly into your browser so you paste the second link i posted above, that would be the direct referer in which case it doesnt work.
What u are saying is correct i didnt notice but what if u access directly

Comment: When you type a URL or paste a URL into your browser, there is no referrer. Referrer applies only when you click from one page to the next.

Answer (score 1):

The referrer of a page is the page that launched the link; in this case clicking on the jsfiddle link above from stackoverflow the referrer in jsfiddle would be `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9695194/whats-wrong-with-this-js-code-implemented-in-this-context`

jsfiddle runs within a frame so you get the referrer of the subframe as the parent; which is why your example test works within jsfiddle. I think you would need to use or top.document.referrer or parent.document.referrer to get the stackoverflow url as the what referred you to the jsfiddle page (if it doesn't break js cross site security limitations)

In case you want to know what a current page's url is (like from within the context of in your second link) you would use document.location.href to get  `http://segurosendirecto.com.ar/cotizador-de-seguros-auto/?kw=hsbc` instead of document.referrer. Then you would find the hsbc at the end of the url. I think  document.location.href may be what you want in your actual site to get at the hsbc parameter.

Comment: im using it for traffic coming from Google to that page so i guess ill keep using document.referer

Comment: what's this got to do with frames? Even if it's being loaded in a frame, the referrer is that of the frame's page loading it...

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not executing properly. Wrap all of your code with:

```
$(function(){

});
```

Then move the entire `<script></script>` block to the head.

A more preferred way is to add that code you your already existing document-ready statement, found in the head tags.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
```

See [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3) for more information.